# Using PrivateObject.Invoke to call a static conversion function do not compile in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, privateobject.invoke

I have a test method where I call an private function that converts a kind of to another kind.

This static function have the following signature:

```
private static Destiny[] Array2Array<Origin,Destiny> (Origin[] OriginVector)
```

Since it's a private function, the tester give an error saying it cannot access it. So I got to this point:

```
Origin[] OriginVector = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
Destiny[] expected = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
Destiny[] actual;
var dummy = new ConversionClass();
var po = new PrivateObject( dummy, new PrivateType(typeof(ConversionClass)));
var acessor = new ConversionClassAcessor(po);

actual = po.Invoke("Array2Array", 
         new [] { typeof(Origin[]), typeof(Destiny[]) }, 
         new object[] { OriginVector } );
```

EDIT: That last line throws an compiler error with the message  "cannot convert type object to Destiny[]". What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What happened here? Mr Shain?

Comment: Instead of using the `Invoke` method, you could consider using the assembly attribute [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx). It'll make your tests much cleaner.

Comment: @MatthiasKoch: the one that solved the question **deleted** his anwer(?!?!?!?) before I could mark it as accepted. But the attribute is nice.

Comment: what solved it? I didn't notice other answers..

Comment: He deleted his answer just a few seconds after posting - I was posting a comment when SO warned that the answer was deleted!!!

Comment: The call was solved but it doesn't see the private method, in the end I created an public function with an `Obsolete` attribute just to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple.. cast it. :D

```
actual = (Destiny[]) po.Invoke("Array2Array", 
     new [] { typeof(Origin[]), typeof(Destiny[]) }, 
     new object[] { OriginVector } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Mr Chris Shain,

I will here reproduce the solution you gave me. Since you deleted your answer, if you add a new one after this, I'll delete this and accept yours as the question's answer.

---

The problem with the code above is that `actual` variable is of type `Destiny[]` and the result of Invoke is **System.Object**. An typecast is needed:

```
actual = (Destiny[]) po.Invoke("Array2Array", 
         new [] { typeof(Origin[]), typeof(Destiny[]) }, 
         new object[] { OriginVector } );
```

Comment: Ohhh... I thought you didn't get this error?! Because you said "it does NOT compile WITH an error".. :/

Comment: It could be better phrased, I agree: "it does not compile, with a "blabla" error message". Anyway I edited it and expect this time to be clearer ;-)