# Using PrivateObject.Invoke to call a static conversion function is not working in Unit test

Tags: c#, privateobject.invoke

**Method:**

```
  private static HipKvp[] GetRequestParameterArray(CaptchaRequestModel request){}
```

**Unit Test:**

```
  HipKvp[] input = (HipKvp[])privObj.Invoke("GetRequestParameterArray", new CaptchaRequestModel[] { result });
```

**Exception:**

```
MissingMethodException was unhandled by user code:
Attempted to access a missing member.
```

I've tried different ways, but not working.

Comment: Know [to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609595/using-privateobject-invoke-to-call-a-static-conversion-function-do-not-compile-i).  Check spelling and object type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396996/how-can-i-use-privateobject-to-access-private-members-of-both-my-class-and-its-p

Check this link - and try passing binding flags;

Answer (score 0):

`PrivateObject.Invoke(String, Object[])` does not touch static members, probably because the members don't necessarily *belong* to the object, but to the class.

You need to use [`PrivateObject.Invoke(String, BindingFlags, Object[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243710.aspx) and specify `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static` in the second parameter like so:

```
HipKvp[] input = (HipKvp[])privObj.Invoke("GetRequestParameterArray", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, new CaptchaRequestModel[] { result });
```